# Can you include two to + infinitives in a sentence

Tags: infinitives, conjunction-reduction

When you're writing a list of actions in the form of infinitive verbs, do you include "to" before each of them?

For example, "Ann wants to learn **to** read and **to** knit."

I tend to think you'd only include the second to if you were trying to emphasize the second verb.

Comment: Strictly a matter of style.

Comment: Your hunch is correct. Both version are grammatical, but one gives greater individual emphasis.

Comment: It's a free choice, but since there's no obvious connection between reading and knitting, I'd include the second "to". But where there is an obvious connection between the verbs, like "read" and "write", I'd probably omit it: "Ann wants to learn to read and write".

Answer (score 0):

"Anne wants to learn to read and knit" sounds to me (educated native English speaker) as if Anne wants to learn to accomplish two things *at the same time*. She may or may not already be able to do one or both of them *separately*.

"Anne wants to learn **to** read and **to** knit" means she wants to learn to do them *separately*, from the starting point of not being able to do *either*. Feels a bit like the Oxford Comma.

Can you walk *and* chew gum? Can you see [what Queen Bey does](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/beyonceknowles/irreplaceable.html) in the first-verse lyrics of *Irreplaceable*?

Comment: This commenter is slightly unsure as to why the answerer feels the need to refer to hisself in the third person. Furthermore, he wonders whether the gentleman could add in some references to his answer, improving it greatly.